# 2000 Peugeot 206 compatible door lock barrels

Tags: locks, citroen, compatibility, peugeot-206

My cars door locks bacame seized due to unusage and I need new ones. My friend who has tons of spare car carts does not have locks for this specific model but has for Citroen Ax, Saxo and Peugeot 106.

Are any of those door locks comptible with my car?

Comment: Take them apart and see...